# component not rendered using react-router v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-router-dom, single-page-application

I am currently working in reactjs projects dashboard webapps. I am also using react-routing for navigating content in website.

I have web app like this.
[image]

When i click 'Dashboard' from sidebar it shows content correctly. Also when i click 'Antrian Pasien' on sidebar.
[image]

But when i click 'Ke Form' inside 'Antrian Pasien' content or page. it doesn't render next component.
[![

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvjgs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvjgs.png)

i want to change content inside page. not just in sidebar. here's my version from web app :
react : 16
react-router-dom : 5.3.0

From index.js code :

```
// import resources and library
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

// import './index.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './assets/scss/style.css';
import './index.css';

// Import Page
import Login from './pages/AuthPage/Login';
import Register from './pages/AuthPage/Register';
import App from './App';


// Import Component


// mapping route
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Route exact path='/' component={App}/>
    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
    <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch , NavLink, HashRouter, useRouteMatch, BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Link, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

import './index.css';
import ImgLogo from './assets/images/img-logo.png';
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard/Dashboard';

import Registration from './pages/Registration/Registration';

import Footer from './component/Footer';
import NavigationBar from './component/Navbar';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Forms from './component/Registration/forms/Forms';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        sidebar: () => <div>Dashboard</div>,
        main: () => (
            <>
                <Dashboard/>
            </>
        )
    },
    {
        path: '/antrian-pasien',
        sidebar: () => <div>Antrian Pasien</div>,
        main: () => 
                <>
                    <Registration/>
                </>
    },
    {
        path: '/antrian-pasien/form-antrian-pasien-baru',
        exact: true,
        sidebar: null,
        main: () => <> <Forms/> </>
    }
]

// Sidebar

const LogoIcon = styled.div`
  margin-left: 1rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
`;

const SidebarNav = styled.div`
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
 
  overflow-y: auto;
`;

const SidebarWrap = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
`;

// Main Content 
const Wrapper = styled.div` 
    display: flex;
`;

const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
    background-color: #f8f9fc;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
`;

const Content = styled.div` 
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
`;

const App = () => {
   return (
    <>
        <Router>
            <Wrapper>
                <div style={{fontSize: '10px'}}>
                    <SidebarNav>
                    <LogoIcon>
                    <img src={ImgLogo} alt="Gambar Logo Siklus Care"></img>
                    </LogoIcon>

                    <SidebarWrap>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <Link to="/antrian-pasien">Antrian Pasien</Link>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </SidebarWrap>
                    </SidebarNav>
                </div>
                <Switch>
                        {routes
                            .filter(({ sidebar }) => !!sidebar)
                            .map((route, index) => (
                                <Route
                                    key={index}
                                    path={route.path}
                                    exact={route.exact}

                                />
                            ))}
                </Switch>
                <ContentWrapper>
                        <Content>
                            <NavigationBar/>
                                <Switch> 
                                    {
                                        routes.filter(({ main }) => !!main)
                                        .map((route, index) => (
                                            <Route key={index} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} children={<route.main/>} />
                                        ))
                                    }    
                                </Switch>     
                        </Content>
                    </ContentWrapper>
            </Wrapper>
        </Router>                            
    </>
   )
}

export default App;
```

Registration.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import GridTwoColumnStart from "../../component/Registration/GridTwoColumnsStart";
import GridTwoColumnsNotEqual from "../../component/Registration/GridTwoColumnsNotEqual";
import GridFullColumn from "../../component/Registration/GridFullColumn";

const Registration = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Link to="/antrian-pasien/form-antrian-pasien-baru">Ke Form</Link>
            <Container>
                    <h4>Registration</h4>
                        <GridTwoColumnStart/>
                        <GridTwoColumnsNotEqual/>
                        <GridFullColumn/>
            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Registration;
```

I don't have any idea, any helps would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issues

1. The `App` component is rendered on the ***exact*** path `"/"`, so when the URL path is anything *other than* `"/"` `App` is unmounted and any descendent routes won't be mounted to be matched.
2. The `App` component is rendering another `Router` nested within the outer main router. This means that any routing/navigation actions that are handled by the inner nested router won't be made known to the main outer router. There should be only one router per app providing a routing context.

## Solution

1. Reorder the root routes and render them into the `Switch` component in inverse order of path specificity and remove the `exact` prop. When ordered correctly that is nearly no need at all to use the `exact` prop to restrict route matching.
2. Remove the nested `BrowserRouter` being rendered in the `App` component.

Code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

// mapping route
const routing = (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/register' component={Register} />
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routing, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import {
  Route,
  Switch,
  NavLink,
  Redirect,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        <div style={{ fontSize: '10px' }}>
          <SidebarNav>
            <LogoIcon>
              <img src={ImgLogo} alt="Gambar Logo Siklus Care" />
            </LogoIcon>

            <SidebarWrap>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/antrian-pasien">Antrian Pasien</Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </SidebarWrap>
          </SidebarNav>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          {routes
            .filter(({ sidebar }) => !!sidebar)
            .map((route, index) => (
              <Route
                key={index}
                path={route.path}
                exact={route.exact}
              />
            ))
          }
        </Switch>
        <ContentWrapper>
          <Content>
            <NavigationBar />
            <Switch> 
              {routes
                .filter(({ main }) => !!main)
                .map((route, index) => (
                  <Route key={index} path={route.path} exact={route.exact} children={<route.main/>} />
                ))
              }    
            </Switch>     
          </Content>
        </ContentWrapper>
      </Wrapper>                           
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me detail solution, my issues is placing exact in the wrong way.